# Changing the textwidth of the notes in Beamer (repost from SO)

Tags: beamer, margins, notes

I've asked this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990312/changing-the-textwidth-of-the-notes-in-beamer-latex) and didn't get a good answer, so I'm reposting it here.

---

I've been using the beamer class to create presentations in LaTeX and I love it. Recently I started using the \note command to add notes to my handout so that I have a printed version with some pointers to remind myself of things I want to say in the lecture.
I have a problem with the longer lines in the notes environment as they seems to spill out of the right end of the page without formatting correctly. I don't know if this is so for a reason, but in any case, I would like to find out how to change it. Clearly, I do not want to change the width of the text everywhere, only in the note environment.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\title{An example of itemize in notes not working in beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$  e^{i\pi}+1=0$$
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]{
\item At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blandiis pra
}
\end{document}
```

which results in: [image]

Without the [itemize] option it works fine.
If you put a \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize} environment manually the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful information to anyone trying to solve a problem like this, but I noticed that changing the theme from Boadilla to something else, or deleting the reference to a theme altogether, solved the problem. FWIW, the two themes I used to test this were Warsaw and Berlin

Comment: I'd like to add that I found the above to be true for the following versions of Beamer: **3.07-2** and **3.10-2**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've isolated the problem down to the `infolines` outer theme and specifically the line:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}
```

towards the end.  What seems to be happening is that the note templates aren't quite configured correctly with regard to *changing* the margins.  Some length that the `itemize` environment uses to figure out its width is not getting set correctly when using notes.  As I've not much idea which lengths these are, and which beamer mucks about with, I've not much of an idea as to how to properly fix this.

However, I have a way to *improperly* fix this.  What I found was that by putting the note within a `minipage` environment of the right width worked.  That reset all the correct widths to the right ones without my having to know any of the 'orrible details!  Of course, that's a bit annoying to put in every time so it's possible to force it by modifying the beamer template for the notes page.  Copying out the default one, and adding the necessary lines, I arrived at:

```
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{note page}{infolines}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \insertvrule{.25\paperheight}{white!90!black}
    \vskip-.25\paperheight
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox{
      \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
      \vskip-0.25\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
        \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
          {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
          \pgftext[base,left]{\footnotesize\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
        \end{pgflowlevelscope}
      \end{pgfpicture}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .25\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % this is an addition
  \insertnote
  \end{minipage}               % this is an addition
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[infolines]
```

and that seemed to work fine!

Comment: Sweet! Hats off Andrew!

Comment: BTW, does this mean it is a bug that should be submitted to the Beamer dev team?

Comment: @Yossi Farjoun: I'd consider mentioning it to them, yes.

Comment: Well, Two of the main developers are users here...but I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Done: http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/57/margins-set-up-wrong-in-note-itemize

Comment: @YossiFarjoun I don't understand the solution given here. What is the name of the file I need to modify? I'm using texlive-core-2012.26892-2 (archlinux). My `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty` looks different.

Comment: @Sebastian: the bitBucket page https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/57/margins-set-up-wrong-in-note-itemize seems to indicate that this is a non issue in newer versions of beamer...can you confirm?

Comment: I downloaded the current release and copied all `base/` content into my texmf directory. Same *margin* result.. pdf is created, but also some errors occurred (in `beamer.cls`). Perhaps @JosephWright can help? I guess opening a new question is what I should do...

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to correct the right margin of note pages in "plain" style:

```
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{note page}{plain2}
{
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % this is an addition
  \insertnote
  \end{minipage}               % this is an addition
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain2]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
```