# Control margins of the note of a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, margins, pgfpages

I have a beamer slide associated with a note.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Blah blah\\~\\
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\note[itemize]{
\item Some long long long long long long long long long long long long long Text
\item Some short text
}

\end{document}
```

On the note page, it seems that the right margin is not set properly such that a long line of text goes beyond the page.

How can I define a right margin **that only applies to note pages**?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1481/36296 you could try the following code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

    \usetheme{Madrid}

    %\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
    \usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

    \usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{note page}{infolines}
{%
    {%
        \scriptsize
        \insertvrule{.25\paperheight}{white!90!black}
        \vskip-.25\paperheight
        \nointerlineskip
        \vbox{
            \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
            \vskip-0.25\paperheight%
            \nointerlineskip
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
                \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
                    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
                        \pgftext[base,left]{\footnotesize\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
                \end{pgflowlevelscope}
            \end{pgfpicture}}
            \nointerlineskip
            \vbox to .25\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
                \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
                \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
                \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
                            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
                            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
                }%
                \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
                \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
                            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
                            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
                }%
                \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
                \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
                            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
                            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
                }%
                \vfil}%
        }%
        \vskip.25em
        \nointerlineskip
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % this is an addition
            \insertnote
        \end{minipage}               % this is an addition
    }
    \makeatother

    \setbeamertemplate{note page}[infolines]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Test}
            Blah blah\\~\\
            \begin{itemize}
                \setlength{\itemsep}{10pt}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}

        \note[itemize]{
            \item Some long long long long long long long long long long long long long Text
            \item Some short text
        }

    \end{document}
```